# How to print both matching lines from two different files?

Tags: awk, text-processing

I have `file1` and `file2` as following. I would like to first find matches between two files based on first column and then print the matching lines from `file1` and `file2`. I have written the desired output below

```
$ cat file1
1,      456,    abcd,  ...
23,     567,    rstc,  ...
45,     678,    rsto,  ...
```

```
$ cat file2
23,     5607,   abcstc, ...
45,     28,     zfgsto, ...
```

Desired output:

```
23,     567,    rstc,    ...
23,     5607,   abcstc,  ...
45,     678,    rsto,    ...
45,     28,     zfgsto,  ...
```

Comment: The answers available are only for one file and not for comparing two different files

Comment: Duplicate file voters. Look closely, I don't beleive this is a duplicate.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about

```
awk -F, 'NR==FNR {a[$1]=$0;next}; $1 in a {print a[$1]; print}' file1 file2
```

Comment: OK just be aware it won't necessarily do what you expect in the case where there are *multiple* instances of the same column1 value.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe using `uniq` to first create the set of lines you want:

```
for pref in $(tail -q -n +2 *.txt | cut -d',' -f 1 | sort | uniq); do grep ^${pref}"," *.txt | cut -d':' -f 2 >> test.res; done
```

**Walkthrough:**

Create set of prefixes using `uniq` (skips first line of each file using `tail`):

```
for pref in $(tail -q -n +2 *.txt | cut -d',' -f 1 | sort | uniq)
```

For each prefix found, `grep` both files for lines starting with it, and remove `grep` "file matched" report using `cut`:

```
do grep ^${pref}"," *.txt | cut -d':' -f 2 >> test.res; done
```